# pre-upload text and video for the future

Tags: plugins, widgets

I want to upload text and a video for a future date.  On that future date, a new post/html is added to the site (without me doing anything that day).

Comment: Please add any code you've tried or mention any research you've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, you should just need to set the publication date of the post in the future and "Publish" it. This should walk you through you what you need to know: http://wordpress.tv/2009/01/14/publishing-your-post-at-a-later-date/